# graphwiz: How to draw an edge from a node to a cluster?

Tags: graphviz

I'd like to draw an edge from a node to the center of a cluster.

Here is an attempt:

```
digraph top {
    compound=true
    node[shape=rectangle]
    subgraph cluster1 {
        a_very_long_label
        b
        i [fixedsize=true,margin=0,width=0,style=invis]
        c
        d
    }
    p->i [lhead=cluster1]
}
```

How can I do it without the "i" node and the arrow's port is centered at the cluster?
[rendered by magjac.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1uwy.png)

Comment: Are you wanting to draw an edge to the center of your cluster regardless of any nodes that might already be positioned at/near the cluster's center?

Comment: @sroush I'd like to draw the edge from one node (South position) to, in this case, the North position of the cluster. (Instead of having four edges to each of nodes (a, b, c, and d) which can get messy.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get pretty close using an "html-like" node label (see https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html)

```
digraph top {
    compound=true
    node[shape=rectangle]
    i [label=<<TABLE CELLSPACING="12" CELLPADDING="8" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1">
    <TR>
      <TD>a_very_long_label</TD>
      <TD>b</TD>
      <TD>c</TD>
      <TD>d</TD>
    </TR>  
    </TABLE>>]

    p->i 
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Probably the best it can get. Thank you!